# untar error - Cannot change mode to rwxr-sr-x

Tags: permissions, tar

I am trying to untar a .gz file , which is stored in the `/root` folder onto a directory in `/mnt/flash2/example`

I use the following command:

```
tar xzf filename.gz --no-same-owner -C /mnt/flash2/example
```

I get the following error:

```
tar: filename: Cannot change mode to rwxr-sr-x: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: @Christopher i used the blkid and df commands. It is a vfat filesystem

Comment: well the problem is I cannot store the untared files to the /root directory (lack of space) , So i am putting it onto the other directory which is of vfat. Now is there a way to go around this? @Christopher

Comment: You might find [gunzip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) more appropriate for `gz` file. For example: `gunzip -c filename.gz >/mnt/flash2/example`

Comment: What i did worked. I made a extracted the tar file in my local machine. Made it to a zip and I secure copied it to my remote switch . I unzipped the zip to my flash drive and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer that helped me here:
https://superuser.com/questions/699225/avoid-errors-from-tar-failing-to-restore-directory-permissions

The error basically occurred because the tarball had two folders (with no files) that did not exist on the destination server.
Evidentally the flag `--no-overwrite-dir` might do the trick.
(See above link)

In my case, I instead manually created those two directories and set the permissions to 755.
When I re-ran the extraction, everything worked perfect!

To recap
Problem:
I was extracting a tar file which had empty WordPress uploads folders `2017` and `2017/01` which were not on the destination server.
`tar -zxvf` created those two folders on the destination server with folder permissions to 775,
and could not change them to 775..

As per the above link, i believe this may happen only if the tarball has empty directories that are not part of an existing tree that you are replacing.

Solution:
-- try the `--no-overwrite-dir` flag
-- manually create and set permissions on the missing (empty?) folders